# What are all the special loot drops in survival mode?

Tags: iron-brigade

In the newly renamed *Iron Brigade* the new survival mode has special loot drops for lasting a certain number of rounds, etc.

What are all the new survival loot drops and what are the conditions to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swamp Survival Rewards**

- Wave 5 L-2 "Faster Blaster" Level 15 Machine Gun
- Wave 10 B0-7T6 The Hole Puncher Level 16 Grenade Launcher
- Wave 15 M3200 Advanced Spurt Rifle Level 16 Sniper Cannon
- Wave 20 Piercing Sniper Turret Level 16 Heavy Turret
- Wave 25 Admiral Archie Level 16 Machine Gun
- Wave 30 Camo Shotgun Turret Level 15 Light Turret
- Wave 35 Explosive Barrel Thrower Level 17 Artillery Cannon
- Wave 40 Diamond Plate Paintjob Level 18 Paintjob
- Wave 45 Bare Vested Level 18 Outfit
- Wave 50 Cowboy Hat Level 19 Hat

**Hospital Survival Rewards**

- Wave 5 80-UNC3 Indirect MG Level 10 Machine Gun
- Wave 10 L4-2Y "Hot Shot" Level 10 Shotgun
- Wave 15 L4-2Y "Hyper" Sniper Level 10 Sniper Cannon
- Wave 20 Shred Machine Gun Turret Level 10 Light Turret
- Wave 25 GL-V "Cluster Thruster" Level 10 Grenade Launcher
- Wave 30 Dampening Coil Cannon Level 10 Artillery Cannon
- Wave 35 Coil Mortar Turret Level 10 Heavy Turret
- Wave 40 R-GNS - Lazio Device Level 10 Broadcaster
- Wave 45 Scrubs Level 10 Outfit
- Wave 50 Medical Mirror Level 10 Hat

**Settlement Survival Rewards**

- Wave 5 Muerte Fiesta Numero 6 Level 15 Shotgun
- Wave 10 Albert Level 15 Sniper Cannon
- Wave 15 Massive Magnet Launcher Level 16 Grenade Launcher
- Wave 20 Explosive Barrel Generator Level 15 Heavy Turret
- Wave 25 The Boomerang Level 17 Artillery Cannon
- Wave 30 Lieutenant Archie Flak Turret Level 16 Light Turret
- Wave 35 Good Vibrations Level 18 Broadcaster
- Wave 40 Psychic Pswirl Level 20 Paintjob
- Wave 45 Smoking Jacket Level 19 Outfit
- Wave 50 Fez Level 20 Hat

Answer (score 3):

Wave 45 is the doctors coat.

Wave 50 is the doctors hat.

Answer (score 2):

Wave 5 reward is a Indirect MG (ricochet) with atp of 4.8 (?).

Wave 10 is a Hot Shot (full auto slug firing shotgun, with almost double the fire rate of a jackhammer)

Wave 15 is a Hyper Sniper, double the power of the Nasty Baby, same fire rate.

Wave 20 is a Shredder MG emplacement which really produces plenty extra scrap. and decent attack power at 3rd lvl. same cost as a regular mg.

Wave 25 is a cluster grenade launcher. 3 extra bomblets after it explodes. More powerful than the sassy basket last I checked. I will fill this in more after I get further.

Answer (score 2):

Wave 30 is a Coil Cannon that creates a slow field

Wave 35 is a Coil Mortar that creates a damage field

Wave 40 is a laser broadcaster that is extremely long range and pinpoint accurate. It appears to damage every enemy along the line it is fired.